# Angular 2 loaded class

Tags: angular, loaded

I have 4 components that should get a class "loaded", when they are ready, but I don't quite know how to handle this in a nice way

The compoenents are not in a ngFor, so they have no index.

```
<div class="component" [ngClass]="{'loaded': loaded1}">1 </div>
<div class="component" [ngClass]="{'loaded': loaded2}">2 </div>
<div class="component" [ngClass]="{'loaded': loaded3}">3 </div>
<div class="component" [ngClass]="{'loaded': loaded4}">4 </div>
```

..

In my class i have a 4 properties. But is this really a good way of doing it, or is there a better / easier. I would prefer to just have 1 loaded property, that influence the components individually

```
export class test {
    public loaded1 = false;
    public loaded2 = false;
    public loaded3 = false;
    public loaded4 = false;

methodForComponent1() {
    this.loaded1 = true;
}
methodForComponent2() {
    this.loaded2 = true;
}
methodForComponent3() {
    this.loaded3 = true;
}
methodForComponent4() {
    this.loaded4 = true;
}

}
```

sd

Comment: you can simply create separate components if it has a different template or similar component for all where you can handle when it loaded by standard angular life cycle. And add a class in the template of this component. Then if you need to do with this component after it loaded from parent component you can handle an event using output. I add example how to do all of this in the answer. Its better way to you because you separate your functionality to different components. Can better encapsulate it and extend the functionality in future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object with a number to a Boolean.

loaded = {}

Comment: Could you give an example please

Answer (score 0):

You can create a component for this four components, where you add one of the lifecycle hooks, that called `ngAfterViewInit()`. You can read about this [there](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks). Then in this component, you can create output event emitter something like this:

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'your-compoent',
  template: '<div [ngClass]="{'loaded': loaded}>Your template</div>'
})
export class YourComponent {
  private loaded:boolean = false; // this for your class
  @Output() componentLoaded = new EventEmitter();

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.loaded = true;
    this.componentLoaded.emit(this.user); //there you emmit your paren component about that your component loaded
  }
}
```

The template of your paren component still can look like in your sample but add the event handler:

```
<your-component (componentLoaded)="yourFunctionInParentComponent($event)"></your-component>// you can add so many component so you need
```

and then in your parent component, you need to add function for handling this event

```
yourFunctionInParentComponent(event){
 //there you can do what you need
}
```

About output and it handling you can read more [there](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

Comment: What if there is no parent component